# How to remove and display this elements when ajax success?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How to remove and display this elements when ajax success ?

i want to remove this elements when success

```
<a class="hyper" id="1234567890">
    <div class="mine">
        <img src="moo.png"/>
    </div>
</a>
```

and display this elements when success

```
<a class="success" id="1234567890">
    <div class="sura">
        <img src="naa.png"/>
    </div>
</a>
```

and this is my ajax `post` code

```
$('body').on('click','.hyper',function() {   
    var my_id = $(this).attr('id');       
    var postData = 'mydata='+my_id+'&time=now';
    $.ajax({        
        type: "POST",
        url: "my_post.php",
        data: postData,
        cache: false,
        success: function() 
            {           

            }       
    });
})
```

When i use follow `Zentoaku`

```
$('#1234567890').removeClass('hyper').addClass('success').html('<div class="sura"><img src="naa.png"/></div>');
```

after success my element display

```
<a class="hyper" id="1234567890">
    <div class="mine">
        <img src="moo.png"/>
    </div>
    <a class="success" id="1234567890">
        <div class="sura">
            <img src="naa.png"/>
        </div>
    </a> 
</a>
```

but after success i want to see this

```
<a class="success" id="1234567890">
    <div class="sura">
        <img src="naa.png"/>
    </div>
</a>
```

how can i do ?

Comment: is the element you want to show present on the page or will it be created dynamicly?

Comment: You must have done something else because test fiddle with my code: http://jsfiddle.net/raooy7x1/, show that it's good solution

Answer (score 2):

To Hide you can use following:

```
success: function() 
{           
     $('.hyper').hide();
}
```

You can also use `remove()` method to completely remove the elements from DOM.

To show use this:

```
success: function() 
{
   $('.success').show();
}
```

You can use `Id` as well as your selector, if you use different ids for both the elements.

**NOTE:** This solution will be applicable when you have your `html` code already exists on your page which you have shown in your question.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has a toggle function, with which you can toggle the visibility of an item.

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Your code then could look like this:

```
$('body').on('click','.hyper',function() {   
    var my_id = $(this).attr('id');       
    var postData = 'mydata='+my_id+'&time=now';
    $.ajax({        
        type: "POST",
        url: "my_post.php",
        data: postData,
        cache: false,
        success: function(my_id) 
        {           
            $('#'+my_id+'.hyper').toggle();
            $('#'+my_id+'.success').toggle();
            }       
   });
})
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#1234567890').removeClass('hyper').addClass('success');
$('#1234567890 > div').removeClass('mine').addClass('sura');
$('#1234567890 > div > img').attr('src', 'naa.png')
```

OR

```
$('#1234567890').removeClass('hyper').addClass('success').html('<div class="sura"><img src="naa.png"/></div>');
```

Comment: this just removes the classes and not the element. actually removing the class is the OP's problem.

Comment: So what? You don't need to remove element if it looks the same and just have different classes. My solution is working: http://jsfiddle.net/raooy7x1/

Comment: you can build a house with a hammer, wood and some nails. this works too! but the op's question was: How to remove `element` and not how to remove `class`. what is if he changes the image name ? than he have to search his source for the image name and change it. in case that hes coding nice, logic and display source is separated. so this solution isn't very nice

Comment: I'm basing on his code. Why should I provide him extensive DOM manipulation method when all he needs is to alter existing element? Sure, code always can go more complex but that's not the point in here.

Comment: the main problem i have with your answere is that this is "hard coded" and this should never be posted as a solution. even if your answere is based on his source, op's source doesn't show a way to code things hard!

Comment: Well, I don't get your point of view, you don't get mine so let's just end this topic. Peace

Comment: Do you agree with me that logic code should be separated from display code ? if yes than this `.html('<div class="sura"><img src="naa.png"/></div>');` is the problem. Lets say image name changes from `naa.png` to `nab.png` in this case he has to edit his logic source and not his display source. and that's my point of view. yours is the solution of the problem. in the end it works, but there are many ways to rome if you understand what i mean. the information im giving is not just for the op, its also for you. and this is not a personal attack. just a hint you should follow.

Comment: I get it, but as a counter example: jQueryUI :) Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: jqueryUI is OOP. so you can use elements. you will never find hard coded things in there. only things like images that belongs to jqueryUI. If the image changes, there will be a new jqueryUI version :)

Comment: Same here, if requirement will change => new version :) It doesn't matter if you write createElement('div'), appendNode, etc. or .html('<div></div>'), it's hard coded anyway. And that's how it's achieved in jqueryui. It's impossible to write specific DOM structure without hard coding. At some point you just have to do it, sooner or later :) offtopic: you're forcing me to think, that hurts :P

Comment: true, but the images in ui belongs to the plugin. hes not writing a plugin. what if i change the ui for me and push it to jqueryui.com so other can use my source... this would end up in a chaos. :) so in a way its kind of hard coded but that's ok. can't come around this. but using custom informations is the bad thing. :) off-topic: sometimes thinking open eyes. im always willing to learn. and this happens by thinking :D